# Text decoration (strike-through) in "Depends on" column of bug lists

Tags: configuration, bugzilla

Bug lists in the Bugzilla installation on ([see this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?resolution=---&product=Bugzilla&query_format=advanced&list_id=15828279&component=Query%2FBug%20List&classification=Server%20Software)) have linked numbers with decoration in the *“Depends on”* column:

[image: Decorated text in Depends-on cells]

which is very helpful for picking a new candidate to assign, but which we miss in the Bugzilla installation of our company:

[image: Plain text in Depends-on cells]

I wasn't able to find out the version they run, but the [linked documentation is about **version 4.2**](https://bmo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/index.html). Our company runs **version 5.0.6**. I tried to find switches in the *Preferences* and *Administration* or information in the bugs of Bugzilla itself, but found nothing so far. I also inspected the HTML source, see these examples of the respective cells in the Mozilla installation (lines reformatted):

open bug

```html
<td class="bz_dependson_column">
<a class="bz_bug_link bz_status_NEW" 
   title="NEW - box-decoration-break: clone affects bidi continuations" 
   href="/show_bug.cgi?id=1569107">
   1569107
</a>
</td>
```

closed bug

```html
<td class="bz_dependson_column">
<a class="bz_bug_link bz_status_RESOLVED bz_closed" 
   title="RESOLVED FIXED - text-decoration-thickness isn't
   being serialized as part of the text-decoration shorthand computed-value"
   href="/show_bug.cgi?id=1574222">
   1574222
</a>
</td>
```

Here a *“Depends on”* cell in our installation:

```html
<td class="bz_dependson_column">
1792
</td>
```

There is no difference related to the bug state.

I was not able to get any useful results by searching the web, also when searching for the classes `bz_bug_link`, `bz_status_NEW` etc., they originate from the classes pool applied to all bug links shown by Bugzilla.

The text-decoration goes back to the CSS:

```css
.bz_obsolete, .bz_inactive, .bz_closed, .bz_CLOSED td {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
}
```

What has to be done to enable links, and therefore classes, for bug numbers shown in the "Depends on" column of bug lists?

Comment: Report a bug to whoever maintains Bugzilla.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for taking the time. Do you *know* that the linking is done by the standard package (and not by some extension)? As I said, the fact that I haven't found anything makes me a little unsure if the error isn't on my end. Only now I did a web search for `"Select a product category to browse:"` and found several 5.0.x installations exposing the same issue.

Comment: I filed a bug report: [1729639 - Missing text-decoration and linking for "Depends on" column in bug list](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1729639)